# How to count how often two different values appear with the same value in their neighbouring cell in EXCEL?

Tags: excel, vba

### --- I HAVE REFORMULATED MY QUESTION TO MAKE IT EASIER TO UNDERSTAND. Please find the new post below! ---

I have a spreadsheet with recipe titles in column A and ingredients in column B. 
[[image: input matrix[1]]

I want to create a Matrix with all ingredients as rows & columns that shows how many times 2 ingredients occur in the same recipe. Sadly my limited knowledge about VLOOKUP, COUNTIFS etc. doesn't help me here!

I would be very happy if you could help me how to build a formula (VBA or normal) for this problem! Thank you very much!

### ---- EDIT ---

To those who have already answered, thank you!
After having received feedback on how to improve my question here is a new approach:

In the picture, you see my input matrix on the left: Names of recipes and ingredients that are the recipes.

On the right, you see the output that I wish for: a grid of all ingredients with the count of how many times 2 ingredients appear in the same recipe.

[Input & Output matrices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drKTK.png)

The command I am looking for should be something like: "For every time ingredient-A (e.g. Gin) appears in a recipe check which other ingredients are in this recipe (e.g. Tonic Water & Cucumber). Then add +1 in the Matrix where Gin and Tonic Water / Gin and Cucumber meet.

I hope this clarifies my question, but don't hesitate to tell me if it's still somehow incomprehensible. THANK YOU!

Comment: I think you have to improve your post in two ways. First you need to clarify what the expected ouput is because as far as I understand your question then no ingredient is used twice in your example data per recipe. Second you have to show what you have tried so far as _could you help me_ ist not a question, see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question/284237#284237).

Comment: So your output should be for example `Vodka - steirerblut, Moscow mule` or `Vodka - 2`?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! This was my first question and I still try to learn how to ask effectively.

Comment: Thank you @Andreas.  I now edited my question in order to make it more comprehensible. Thank you for your patience I notice that it's harder to ask a good question than I thought :)

Answer (score 0):

Your input does not actually show any examples of ingredients appearing twice within a recipe, but assuming you meant something like in my example below, you can simply use a pivot table:

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer. I think I have not formulated my question properly yesterday. I now edited my question. Is this comprehensible?